# Editor not displaying dynamically after clicking on the button

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, html, wp-editor

I am displaying the field dynamically in the admin panel. I have a button called `Add more fields`. The user can add the custom field dynamically. As of now, it's working but the issue is the editor not displaying properly. Check the screenshot below

[image]

I am using below code

```
function woocommerce_register_2col_layout_fields() {
    global $post;
    // Nonce field to validate form request came from current site
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'layout' );
    // Output the field
    echo '<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="addMore_layout">Add more fields</a>';
    echo '<div class="create_custom_layout" id="create_custom_layout"><div class="row">';
        echo '<div class="col-md-6">';
            echo '<h4>Description</h4>';
            //We first get the post_meta from the DB if there's any there.
            $description        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pDescription', true );
            //Second ID the field.
            $description_field  = 'pDescription';
            //Provide the settings arguments for this specific editor in an array
            $description_args   = array( 'media_buttons' => false, 'textarea_rows' => 12, 'textarea_name' => 'pDescription[]',
            'editor_class' => 'description-editor widefat', 'wpautop' => true );
            wp_editor( $description, $description_field, $description_args );
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="col-md-6">
            <h4>Banner image</h4>
            <input type="button" id="meta-image-button" class="button" value="Choose or Upload an Image" style="padding: 8px 10px; height: auto; line-height: normal;"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="pimage[]" id="meta-image" class="meta_image" value="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pimage', true ).'" /><br />
            <img style="width: 100px;height: 100px;object-fit: cover;" id="meta-image-preview" src="'.get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'pimage', true ).'" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .create_custom_layout .row{display: flex;flex-wrap: wrap;}
    .create_custom_layout .col-md-6 {
        flex: 0 0 auto;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>
<script>
jQuery("#meta-image-button").click(function() {
        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
    jQuery("#meta-image").val(attachment.url);
        jQuery("#meta-image-preview").attr("src",attachment.url);
            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
        }
        wp.media.editor.open();
        return false;
    });


  jQuery(function() {
        jQuery("#addMore_layout").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery("#create_custom_layout").append(`<div class=\'row\'><div class=\'col-md-6\'><h4>Description</h4>';
  $description1        = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'pDescription', true );
  //Second ID the field.
  $description_field1  = 'pDescription';
  //Provide the settings arguments for this specific editor in an array
  $description_args1   = array('media_buttons' => false,'textarea_rows' => 12,'textarea_name' =>'pDescription[]','editor_class' =>'description-editor widefat', 'wpautop' => true);
  wp_editor($description1,$description_field1,$description_args1);
  echo'</div><div class=\'col-md-6\'><input type=\'button\' id=\'meta-image-button\' class=\'button\' value=\'Choose or Upload an Image\' style=\'padding: 8px 10px; height: auto; line-height: normal;\'/><input type=\'hidden\' name=\'pimage[]\' id=\'meta-image\' class=\'meta_image\' /><br /><img style=\'width: 100px;height: 100px;object-fit: cover;\' id=\'meta-image-preview\'  /></div></div>`);
       
          })
      });
    
  </script>';

}
```

Comment: the issue is the editor not displaying properly. - this is not a very descriptive explanation, how should the editor look, what problems do you have, is there any debug code - php or js? Try to be as clear as possible in order that people can help.

Comment: Probably a JS error, did you look at  the browser dev console for error messages? If I had to guess, your PHP code is not being executed but is instead being put inside the string, and ending up on the frontend, but you haven't actually checked the HTML to see if it's right. If so, this is a syntax problem, not a WordPress problem

Comment: Also you can't just embed `get_post_meta` in the middle of a Javascript block like that, it's a huge security hole for javascript injection attacks. Take a look at `wp_localise_script`

Comment: @QStudio, I updated the function code and added the screenshot in the question. When I click on add more fields then I am getting the editor issue.

Comment: @TomJNowell, I checked. There is no error in the console.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is  because you mixed PHP and Javascript incorrectly, in your very last jQuery code. You can't and shouldn't call `wp_editor` inside a script tag. If you want to create a new WP Editor when you click a button, that is not how you do it. Instead you should ask how to create WP Editor's using javascript instead of PHP, rather than how to fix your attempt ( I believe that question has already been asked and answered on the site )

Comment: @TomJNowell, I haven't asked about PHP. Can you help me out in this? I found this link https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/274592/how-to-create-wp-editor-using-javascript but little bit confused

Comment: You can't  use the PHP `wp_editor` function to create new editors when a button is clicked, it must be done using Javascript. Your  code currentlly tries and fails to do it in PHP

Comment: @TomJNowell, I agreed with your last comment. I am trying to find the solution using a script